# Selenium Locators: Nested query with partial matches on multiple elements

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am looking for stable nested query in order to locate the "input" field using its "type" or "class" property (either using cssSelecor or using xpath).

Something like :
div class matches("panel-wrap") / div class matches("panel-body") / div class matches("panel-class") / input type=text or input class matches("text-field")

Basically a combination of nested query with partial matches on class name or id.

```
<div id="12-ext-5" class="fff-panel-wrap-rr">
<div id="30-ext-6" class="ggg-panel-body-gg">
<div id="40-ext-9" class="ddd-panel-class-hh">
<input id="24-ext-9" class="grr-text-field-gen00" type="text" name="ext-comp-r">
```

Any help?

Comment: Looks like the id is never unique?

Answer (score 1):

> Something like : div class matches("panel-wrap") / div class matches("panel-body") / div class matches("panel-class") / input type=text or input class matches("text-field")

Translating above sentence into xpath would bring up something like this (formatted for readability) :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'panel-wrap')]
/div[contains(@class, 'panel-body')]
/div[contains(@class, 'panel-class')]
/input[@type='text' or contains(@class, 'text-field')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this css help?

```
input[class^='grr-text-field'][type='text'][name='ext-comp-r']
```

Notice the class is a partial match. I assumed `-gen00` was dynamically added.

The following should be the way to write css selector you have described. However, I do not suggest you to write selector like this

```
div[class*='panel-wrap']>div[class*='panel-body']>[class*='panel-class']>input[class*='text-field']
```

Comment: @bpk see my edit. And, to be precise give me more html, at least from the parent node and I can give you better selector

Comment: I tried "input[class^='grr-text-field']" but it doesn't work. If I give the full class as "input[class^='grr-text-field-gen00']" it works. What's wrong?

Comment: probably because other elements are matching same partial class